Turn off all monitors with Windows API
I want to turn off all monitors programmatically, as if the screen off time in Windows Settings had elapsed. This means, that any user input (e.g., keypress or mouse move) would turn the monitors back on.
I am looking for a solution that

is not "somewhat of a hack", like this answer;
is as simple as possible: the mentioned answer links to Raymond Chen's article, which suggests creating a dummy window, thus, let's create the simplest window;
is in C++.

Note, that the following program puts the computer to sleep instead of turning all monitors off, even though the documentation of SC_MONITORPOWER says, 2 has to turn them off.
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    SendNotifyMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
}

I found the above code by googling. The Google results contained SendMessage instead of SendNotifyMessageW. I replaced the function because I found that sometimes the call lasts long (see this question). Also note, that Raymond Chen discouraged broadcasting this message in his article.

The code that handles this message is in DefWindowProc, so the simplest (and correct) solution would be to create a dummy window (it can be message-only, does not need to be visible), and then call DefWindowProc on it to send the command.

Raymond Chen even said as much in the linked article: "The correct solution is not to post messages to random windows. If you want the message to go through window message default processing, create a window and process it yourself. Don’t try to trick some other window (or in this case, hundreds of other windows simultaneously) into doing it for you."

For reference: message-only windows on Microsoft Learn. I still suppose, (LPARAM) 2 will put my computer to sleep. I think, this depends on some Windows settings, like "modern suspend mode".

https://github.com/Brandon-T/HDMI/blob/master/main.cpp#L74 and https://github.com/Brandon-T/HDMI/blob/master/Monitor.cpp#L168
This does it. It has a Message only Window that's invisible, and listeners for HDMI monitor connect/disconnect, and has a function to TurnOff the display/monitor. Be aware that I wrote the code over 10 years ago, so I haven't tested it since. It was last working on my TV and ASUS laptop display + Acer predator monitor at the time, to fix a bug in AMD display driver (by turning the monitor off, then on, after 1s delay). Hopefully still works.

@Brandon: But, you are broadcasting SC_MONITORPOWER in Monitor.cpp. It should be sent to the message-only window only, shouldn't it?

It seems that when the screen turns off, the system will enter Modern Standby. You could try to disable Modern standby.

@Dr.Gut; You're right. You can just pass in the window handle instead. The window is already create in main, so you can add an HWND parameter, and just pass in the window that was created, then it should still work fine.

I only know that SetSuspendState can make the computer enter a suspend (sleep) state or hibernation (S4)
I always press the physical button on my computer to turn off the screen when I step away from the computer, and call SetSuspendState to shut down the computer after my program finishes executing.

Archive of Raymond Chen's article containing original comments.
https://web.archive.org/web/20231207142757/https://bytepointer.com/resources/old_new_thing/20060613_196_fumbling_around_in_the_dark_and_stumbling_across_the_wrong_solution.htm

What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?

@Brandon: Is this what you mean? Is there anything you can simplify? Note, that you didn't pass hInstance to CreateWindowEx. I have corrected that. Problem: This program makes my computer sleep, instead of turning the monitors off.

@Dr.Gut; You might have to mess with your windows power saving settings. I'd also use PostMessage instead.

@Brandon: If I replace SendMessageW with PostMessageW, the message has no effect. Here is an improved version. It puts the entire code into a TurnOffAllMonitors() function, and unregisters the window class at the end. ▞ Why is this so complicated?... I know, that it is possible to write such a program, because Windows can turn off all monitors when its timer expires. Regardless of your power settings.

Hmm if it's still going to sleep somehow, try using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate
I'm out of ideas. I'm not really sure if it'll work, but you need to call the above in a loop. It will tell the system to stay active (hopefully). How do you know if the system is sleeping or is in a hibernation state?

powercfg /sleepstudy can distinguish sleep from screen off.

modern standby session is defined as one instance of the screen turning off and back on again. the SleepStudy report will break this down into the time spent quiescing the system (the Screen Off state), and the time spent in its long term low power state (the Sleep state).
Whether have you tried to disable Modern standby?

@Jeaninez-MSFT: I disabled Modern Standby (link). I have no option in BIOS to enable Legacy Sleep (S3), therefore I was left with no Sleep option in Start Menu > Power at all. In powercfg /a all sleep states were not available. Running the above TurnOffAllMonitors() function indeed turns off the monitors. Interestingly, there is no trace of this event (and the resume event) in powercfg /sleepstudy. Any advice for those who want to keep Modern Standby, but still turn off all monitors?

If you keep Modern Standby, when you turn off all monitors, Modern Standby will be triggered. When a system enters modern standby‐‐that is, when the screen turns off‐‐its software and applications must be made ready to enter its long term, low power sleep state. Following the display turning off, the system will begin quiescing software activities to enter modern sleep.

@Jeaninez-MSFT: I cannot confirm your statement. Windows can turn off all monitors. When its screen off timer elapses, it does that.

If you don't disable Modern standby, when the display turning off, the system will begin quiescing software activities to enter modern sleep. Refer to the Doc: Prepare software for modern standby

@Jeaninez-MSFT: You have already said that, I have already replied to that, you ignored the reply, and repeated what you said. What should I do now? Should I repeat the 3rd time, that it is possible to write such a function, because Windows can turn off all monitors? See the 1st and 2nd time I said that.
